# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot connect to wired network (Ethernet)

Tags: ethernet, 18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my machine when installation finished, it is unable to configure the network, it always shows **Cable unplugged**, everything is working well on the operating systems, such as Windows with the same network configuration.

So what should I do?

Thanks!!

Comment: Two possibilities I can think of.  I am not an expert.  Your network card is no longer supported.  Something went wrong in the install. Hidden in /etc/network manager you may find a setting to enable or disable networkmanager from managing the connections.  Make sure that is enabled.   THIRDLY you can put the live cd or usb back in and see if it all works from a live session.

Comment: @walttheboss Thanks! The problem was with the network card, so now it is OK.